# Globally Log Catch Exception e

Tags: java, exception

Suppose that I have a legacy java application with thousands of lines of code which do:

```
try {
   // stuff 
} catch (Exception e) {
   // eat the exception
}
```

Is there any global option that I could flip or 3rd party JAR which would log all "eaten" exceptions? I know that I could do a massive find replace (search for catch (Exception e) { and replace it with catch(Exception e) { logException(e);) but I was wondering if there was a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could perhaps provide your own implementation of `Exception` which logs the stack-trace in the constructor. From the man page of java:

> **-Xbootclasspath:bootclasspath**
>   Specify a colon-separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>   and ZIP archives to search for boot class files. These are
>   used in place of the boot class files included in the Java 2
>   SDK.

Comment: Probably not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a place where Aspect Oriented Programming could come in handy.  You could set up an exception handler pointcut.  Check out [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php) for a nice AOP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the code catches the exception and does nothing with it, then there's nothing you can do to change that without changing the code.

A find-replace should work. However, I would also strongly recommend checking it with [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) afterward to make sure that you found all instances of this problem. (FindBugs should be a part of your process anyway, but I'm just pointing it out in case anyone who reads this doesn't already use it.)

Comment: Aspect Oriented Programming would let you log exceptions without changing the original code, as Rob Di Marco noted in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820259/globally-log-catch-exception-e/2820381#2820381).

Comment: @markusk: Point taken; there are actually several ways to do it. I've left this answer up mainly for the FindBugs part.

Comment: In that case, why not delete the first paragraph of your answer? Your recommendation of FindBugs is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to handle any uncaught exceptions:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
  new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      //handle the exception
    }
});
```

Comment: But that's not what he asks for.

Comment: Good answer to the wrong question.  The exceptions the OP is dealing with are caught, not uncaught